# table_open_cache increase issue - MariaDB 10.2

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf, mariadb-10.2

I'm trying to increase to 9000 but MariaDB sets it at 4895 automatically.

Here is my simple config
https://pastebin.com/raw/4eFiuFSv

MySQLTuner output:

```
Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/cp.goal.ge.err file
Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/cp.goal.ge.err file
Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64:

Beware that open_files_limit (10000) variable

should be greater than table_open_cache (4895)

Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait
Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys

Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (=0)
    query_cache_type (=0)
    query_cache_size (> 125M)
    table_open_cache (> 4895)
```

Comment: Look in your log file `/var/lib/mysql/cp.goal.ge.err` to see if there are any references to this variable.

Comment: @eroomydna Looked for it. tail -f /var/lib/mysql/cp.goal.ge.err and restarting mariadb server several times to see if there is any warnings or similar output but nothing goes here :(

Comment: Have you tried setting this variable dynamically? E.g. log in with the `mysql` client and execute: `SET GLOBAL table_open_cache=9000;` Does that work?

Comment: @dbdemon Yes. It works. But as you know it resets this value after restarting. This is main reason I need to set it in my.cnf

Comment: @user3446664 Use ulimit -a to find out what the limit is for Open Files.  If you know you want table_open_cache=9000, then other needs for open files such as open_table_definitions.  Suggest you raise the limit to liniux with  ulimit -n 18000 to leave some for other purposes.  Posting the ENTIRE MySQL Tuner report would be helpful, even though some of their recommendations should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 3 different reasons why MariaDB might reset this variable. In order of most to least likely explanation:

1. You have another .cnf file where the `table_open_cache` variable is being set to 4895.
2. The MariaDB Systemd unit file (or SysV init script on older Linux versions) is overwriting the variable value you've set.
3. You're running a non-standard MariaDB server that's been compiled with a hard-coded value for `table_open_cache`. (Unlikely!)

Additionally, it's possible that another software (such as cPanel) might change the variable dynamically after MariaDB has started.

To see which options the MariaDB server will get from the option files, run:

```
mysqld --print-defaults
```

To find all the places where the MariaDB server is looking for .cnf files, run:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep -A 1 'Default options are read'
```

You can then `grep` each of these files to see if you find any instances of `table_open_cache` or `table-open-cache`.

For reference, you should be able to see the current value of the variable with:

```
show global variables like 'table_open_cache';
```

And you may also want to consult this page in the MariaDB Knowledge Base: [Optimizing table_open_cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-table_open_cache/).

Comment: Thanks. Here is output of commands https://pastebin.com/raw/0nCTCHrt

Comment: Sorry not to mentioning it, but there is cPanel installed on this server.
So, I have found warning message in log file. Something is changing open_cache and open_files_limit options. Reporting it to cPanel

Comment: @user3446664 Ah, so maybe cPanel is changing the variables after MariaDB has started. Very cunning! I'll add that to my answer to make it more helpful to others.

Comment: #4:  the OS's `ulimit` is inherited into MySQL and leads to capping `table_open_cache`.